# How to make this slide roll each time I press the button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I managed to make it run, but only once.

jsfiddle.net/geyck9jL/

How to make this slide roll each time I press the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a little something for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/ajvdx2ct/

First, you have to correctly define the possible positions.
Then, using an array, you can "cycle" the elements on each click event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Define the 3 possible positions
  var pos1 = {    // Same as CSS slLeft
      height: '210px',
      width: '280px',
      left: "10%",
      'margin-left':0,
      top: "8%"
    };
  var pos2 = {    // // Same as CSS slMiddle
      height: '300px',
      width: '400px',
      left: '50%',
        'margin-left':'-25%',
        top: '3%'
    };
  var pos3 = {    // // Same as CSS slRight
      height: '210px',
      width: '280px',
      left: "55%",
      'margin-left':0,
      top: "8%"
    };

  // Define an array of divs containing pictures an caption
  var divArray = [$("#slRight"),$("#slLeft"),$("#slMiddle")];

  // The click function
  $("button").click(function() {

    divArray[0].animate(pos1, "slow");
    $(divArray[0]).css('z-index', '2', "slow");

    divArray[1].animate(pos2, "slow");
    $(divArray[1]).css('z-index', '3', "slow");

    divArray[2].animate(pos3, "slow");
    $(divArray[2]).css('z-index', '1', "slow");

    // Rotate elements in divArray
    divArray = [divArray[2],divArray[0],divArray[1]];
  });
});
```

Comment: Dude, you are awesome. Thank you so much <3.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would change your css to be classes not ids.  So you would have '.sl1 {//some css}, etc.

Second, I would iterate over an array of the divs, so if you want to add another in the future, your code doesn't have to be completely re-written.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    index       = 0;
    arrDivs     = [$("#derp"),$("#dorp"),$("#dirp")];

    $("button").click(function(){   
        curDiv          = arrDivs[index];       //get the next div
        $.each(arrDivs,function(i){ //loop over your divs
            if(arrDivs[i] == curDiv) {  //this is the active div
            //...... do something to your active div
            } else {
            //.....do something to your inactive divs
            }
        })
        if(index >= (arrDivs.length-1)) {       //check if we are at the end of the array
            index = 0;                          //set the index to zero or first position
        } else {
            index++;                            //increment the index
        }
    });
});
```